# If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and non-negative random variables, then $\mathbb{E}(XY) = \mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, expected-value

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, then
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(XY) = \mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)
\end{align*}

Here is my attempt:

Since $X = X^{+} - X^{-}$ and $Y = Y^{+} - Y^{-}$, it suffices to prove the desired result for $X\geq 0$ and $Y\geq 0$.

In such case, there are two sequences of non-decreasing and non-negative simple random variables such that $X_{n}\to X$ and $Y_{n}\to Y$.

Due to the MCT (Monotone Convergence Theorem) and the assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, we conclude
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(XY) & = \mathbb{E}(\lim_{n\to\infty}X_{n}\lim_{n\to\infty}Y_{n})\\\\
& = \mathbb{E}(\lim_{n\to\infty}X_{n}Y_{n})\\\\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}(X_{n}Y_{n})\\\\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}(X_{n})\mathbb{E}(Y_{n})\\\\
& = \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}(X_{n})\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}(Y_{n})\\\\
& = \mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y).
\end{align*}

Can anyone criticize my solution?

Comment: Looks good.  The statement has some problems, though, if $E[X]=0$ and $E[Y]=\infty$.  (The proof of course also assumes the result for simple variables).

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the feedback. However the random variables $X$ and $Y$ need not be simple. Since they are non-negative, they can be approximated by sequences of simple, non-negative and non-decreasing random variables so that we can apply the MCT.

Comment: @user1234 Inherently, you are taking three steps: Computing the result for indicator functions, simple functions, positive functions and the original functions. As an interesting exercise, try to generalize it to "something like all formulae made of +, *, $E$", assuming everything is integrable. (Use induction over the formula structure.) Then you have not to do the same boring step-down procedure again. I did it during my master thesis, but it is a bit technical.

Comment: @user7427029 Thanks for the feedback. I will try to proceed as suggested.

Comment: Ups, I looked it up: It is a bit more technical and some knowledge of mathematical logic and Nonstandard analysis might be helpful.

Comment: @user1234 : I mean that within your proof, you are implicitly assuming that you already know the result holds for simple random variables (since you assumed $E[X_nY_n]=E[X_n]E[Y_n]$).

Comment: @Michael Yes, indeed. We have already proven such result for simple random variables previously.

Answer (score 1):

The last step is wrong in some situations. For example, if $X=0$ and $EY=\infty$ then you are saying that $a_n \to 0$ and $b_n \to \infty$ implies $a_nb_n  \to 0$ (Recall that $(0)(\infty)=0$ by convention). This is, of course, false.   This case and  the case $Y=0$ and $EX=\infty$ have to be treated separately.